# Converting a dictionary with nested lists into a CSV file

Tags: python, list, loops, csv, dictionary

Been having a hard time trying to convert this dictionary with nested lists into a CSV file. I have a CSV file I am filtering - https://easyupload.io/8zobej. I turned it into a dictionary then cleaned it up. I am now stuck on trying to output it to a CSV and I don't know what to do. I've tried many different combinations of DictWriter and writerows but I keep coming up short. I am now trying to come up with a for loop that would go through the dictionary and output the value it finds to the CSV.

Here is my code - please excuse the comments - I was trying many things.

```
def dataSorter(filename:str):
    """
    
    The defined function scans the inputted CSV file with 2 columns (Category, value) and sorts the values into categories.
    Giving us lists of values for each category
    
    Done by 
    
    
    """
    #Open the input csv file and parse them by comma delimited
    with open(filename) as inputcsv:
        readcsv = csv.reader(inputcsv, delimiter = ',')
        sortedData = {}
        
        #skips first row
        next(readcsv)
        
        #loops through file and assigns values to the key in dictionary "sortedData"
        for i in readcsv:
            category = i[0]
            if category not in sortedData:
                sortedData[category] = [i[1]]
            else:
                if i[1] not in sortedData[category]:
                    sortedData[category].append(i[1])
                    sortedData[category].sort()
        for category in sortedData.keys():
            sortedData[category].sort()
```

Comment: have you tried pandas?

Comment: And could you take out the comments its hard to read

Comment: @PrestigeDev I have and it keeps telling me my arrays are not matched. I have lists that are longer/shorter than others.

Comment: @PrestigeDev will do

Comment: @j1-lee I am not sure stack overflow will let me attach the file. The file is 2 columns with 1000 rows. 1st column is category and 2nd column is the values

Comment: @AusamahHobbi just put the first 10-20 lines in your question. That should be enough to allow demonstrating your problem

Comment: @AusamahHobbi I meant that you should include the first 10-20 lines of the *csv* file in your question. We need all the code...